# Pentaho cde & Report-designer source

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer, report-designer

How to learn penatho cde dashboard and reports or how to start pentaho cde and reports and is there any books or source files, youtube channel e.t.c to learn became a good pentaho cde developer.if any books or url please share me.

I want to search for good book or src files which will help to  develop the cde and reports.

Answer (score 0):

For learning Pentaho Reporting, I used this book published by PacktPub: https://www.packtpub.com/product/pentaho-5-0-reporting-by-example-beginner-s-guide/9781782162247. It is written for an old version, but nothing has changed much, so you can mainly use it for a new version too. There's another book in PacktPub written for version 8, I haven't tried it since Pentaho wasn't a good match for our reporting needs and it's mostly abandoned since it was a acquired by Hitachi Vantara, with only maintenance releases and the few new features available only in the Commercial version.

For CDE I couldn't find a good step-by-step book, there's a book published by PacktPub that have some information: https://www.packtpub.com/product/learning-pentaho-ctools/9781785283420, but it's not step by step, I'm not a web developer, so I couldn't follow it so easily as the reporting book, I didn't dedicated it as much time either since my company decided that Pentaho wasn't a good match for us.